# Finding Occurrences SUM using Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I need to group by at least one occurrence greater than 0 and I need to sum it to last occurance. My code is below

```
data = {'id': 
     [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
'timeatAcc': 
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
}
df =pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['id','timeatAcc'])
df['consecutive'] =  df['id'].groupby((df['timeatAcc'] != 
df['timeatAcc'].shift()).cumsum()).transform('size') * df['timeatAcc']
print(df)
```

Current Output

[image]

Expected output

[image]

Need help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `groupby().diff()`:

```
df['Occurences'] = df.groupby('id')['timeatAcc'].diff(-1).eq(1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    id  timeatAcc  Occurences
0    7          0           0
1    7          0           0
2    7          0           0
3    7          0           0
4    7          0           0
5    7          0           0
6    7          0           0
7    7          0           0
8    7          1           0
9    7          1           0
10   7          1           1
11   7          0           0
12   7          0           0
13   7          1           0
14   7          1           1
15   7          0           0
16   7          0           0
17   7          1           0
18   7          1           0
19   7          1           0
20   1          1           0
21   1          1           0
22   1          1           1
23   1          0           0
24   1          0           0
25   1          0           0
26   1          0           0
27   1          0           0
28   1          1           0
29   1          1           0
30   1          1           1
31   1          0           0
32   1          0           0
33   1          1           0
34   1          1           1
35   1          0           0
36   1          0           0
37   1          0           0
38   1          0           0
39   1          0           0
```

---

**Update**: to get the sum instead of `1`:

df['Occurences'] = df.groupby(['id', df['timeatAcc'].eq(0).cumsum()])['timeatAcc'].transform('sum')

df['Occurences'] = np.where(df.groupby('id')['timeatAcc'].diff(-1).eq(1).astype(int)
, df['Occurences'], 0)

Output:

```
    id  timeatAcc  Occurences
0    7          0           0
1    7          0           0
2    7          0           0
3    7          0           0
4    7          0           0
5    7          0           0
6    7          0           0
7    7          0           0
8    7          1           0
9    7          1           0
10   7          1           3
11   7          0           0
12   7          0           0
13   7          1           0
14   7          1           2
15   7          0           0
16   7          0           0
17   7          1           0
18   7          1           0
19   7          1           0
20   1          1           0
21   1          1           0
22   1          1           3
23   1          0           0
24   1          0           0
25   1          0           0
26   1          0           0
27   1          0           0
28   1          1           0
29   1          1           0
30   1          1           3
31   1          0           0
32   1          0           0
33   1          1           0
34   1          1           2
35   1          0           0
36   1          0           0
37   1          0           0
38   1          0           0
39   1          0           0
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I have one more doubt can we put the sum at last occurrence rather than putting a 1